# Identifying states (or clusters) in multivariate mixed-type time series

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, clustering, multivariate-analysis, hidden-markov-model

I have multivariate time series with mixed data types, which includes continuous variables, binary variables, and variables with bimodal distributions. I need to identify distinct states or epochs in this time series.

[image]

So far I used sliding window to smooth the scaled data and applied k-means clustering (in the picture). But I wonder if there is a more appropriate solution, especially to avoid smoothing.

**For more context:** the data describes behaviour of players in a game. For example, hit or miss (1 or 0) and reaction time (continuous).
The goal is to identify distinct states in behaviour that don't switch too often (that wouldn't make sense in my case). The states should ideally capture temporal patterns in the data, like variability of reaction time or stable but low performance vs stable high performance etc. I don't have much experience in machine learning and would really appreciate any advice on how to approach this problem. So far I noticed that there are two important questions:

1. How to meaningfully measure distance between feature vectors, especially if the data is mixed type?
2. How to take into account the temporal aspect ?

P.S. I work in python

Comment: What about a hidden markov model? See the tag [tag:hidden-markov-model]

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen sorry for a late reply to your comment. I just got back to this project. Indeed, I have been suggested to use HMMs multiple times! I have tried it and encountered two problems: 
1) mixing continuous and discreet values seems to be an issue 
2) the states are switching very often, setting transition probs to 0.9 or 1 doesn't really solve it. 
Of course, smoothing the data helps with both these problems but I was hoping I could use the raw data.  Could be that I am not aware of some specific type of an HMMs that is more suitable for my problem? Thank you!